# Stimulate Ctrl+g Keypress in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I was working on a project and I need a code to stimulate keypress <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> in *Javascript*.

Comment: You can't do that.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What result of a `Ctrl+g` are you wanting to simulate?

Comment: you mean an onkeydown that pretends it was ctrl-g that was pressed?

Comment: Ctrl+g enable/disables Google Transliteration in a webpage. I've tried other ways but none work. This is my last resort.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158847/is-there-a-way-to-simulate-key-presses-or-a-click-with-javascript

Comment: Still not working....

Comment: You probably need to buy something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_QuickTest_Professional

Answer (score 1):

There was a similar question recently:

[Simulate Shift+Esc combination using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302664/simulate-shiftesc-combination-using-javascript#comment58315815_35302664)

Long story short, you can simulate clicks and keypresses which will work on the webpage and trigger that webpage's functions. What you're trying to do is use the browser's functions; simulated events don't travel all the way to the browser, they stay on the webpage because they originated on the webpage. If the browser doesn't have an API for this particular action, you cannot trigger it on the page.

**EDIT**
Looks like Google Translate has its own Javascript package, which you can utilize like any other library on your webpage. [Here's a tutorial.](https://davidwalsh.name/google-translate-api)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
//global vars
var ctrlpressed = false;
var gpressed = false;

document.onkeydown = function(event){ //Event listener: once any key is pressed, run this function

    if(event.keyCode == 17){ //if CTRL is pressed, change the boolean of ctrlpressed to true.
        ctrlpressed = true;
    }

    if(event.keyCode == 71){ //if G is pressed, change the boolean of ctrlpressed to true.
        gpressed = true;
    }

    if (gpressed === true && ctrlpressed === true) //if both of them are pressed together, generate a message in the client's console
    {
    console.log("Both pressed together");
    }


}   

document.onkeyup = function(event){ //Event listener: once any key is released, reset the booleans above
    ctrlpressed = false;
    gpressed = false;
}   
</script>
```

Worked fine for me, everytime I click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> it console.log it.

Comment: I had a button which when clicked on, it stimulates the keypress of Control+g. Could you please explain your above code. Sorry, I am a beginner so Im having problems. Thanks :)

Comment: If you read OP's comments, he wants Ctrl+G doing a specific thing (enable/disable google translate). Your code will trigger Ctrl+G just fine, but it won't touch google translate api. See my answer below

Comment: Ctrl + g is just another method of word searching in chrome, I don't see how it's got anything to do with google translate. You can't change google chrome's shortcuts. OP, I've added more explanation, check the comments (//)

Answer (score 0):

`Press ctrl+g to check the result`This code working fine.
Run snippet code

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing</title>
</head>
<script>
$(document).bind('keydown', function (event) {
            if (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) {
                switch (String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase()) {
                    case 's':
                        event.preventDefault();
                        alert('ctrl-s');
                        break;
                    case 'f':
                        event.preventDefault();
                         alert('ctrl-f');
                        break;
                    case 'g':
                        event.preventDefault();
                                  alert('ctrl-g');
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
</script>
<body>

<h2>Javascript testing</h2>


</body>
</html>
```

and Press ctrl+s , ctrl+f and ctrl+g for testing.